# Why percentages of width of td in CSS don't seem to work?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a table in HTML/CSS and I am having trouble with the width of the cells. When I put "width: 24%" in the "table td" in CSS the table cells stays in the size that I want. OK, great. But when I put "width: 15%" the table cells grows??? And when I put "width: 8%" it takes all the space of the page. Why?

Here is the HTML code of the table:

```
<table  border="1">
        <caption>RGB colors and their combinations</caption>
        <tr>
            <td> </td> <td bgcolor="#FF0000">RED</td> <td bgcolor="#00FF00">GREEN</td> <td bgcolor="#0000FF">BLUE</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td bgcolor="#FF0000">RED</td> <td bgcolor="#FF0000"> </td> <td bgcolor="#FFFF00"> </td> <td bgcolor="#FF00FF"> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td bgcolor="#00FF00">GREEN</td> <td bgcolor="#FFFF00"> </td> <td bgcolor="#00FF00"> </td> <td bgcolor="#00FFFF"> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td bgcolor="#0000FF">BLUE</td> <td bgcolor="#FF00FF"> </td> <td bgcolor="00FFFF"> </td> <td bgcolor="#0000FF"> </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

And here is all the CSS code:

```
h1{
    color: gray;
    font-family: Bodoni, serif;
}

body{
    text-decoration: blink;
    font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding: 5%;
    padding-top: 1%;
}

table{
    margin: 2.5%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    table-layout: fixed;
}
caption{
    caption-side: bottom;
}

.italico{
    font-style: italic;
}

.img_flickr{
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 2.5%;
}

.img_flickr > a > img{
    width: 50%;
    min-width: 200px;
}

table tr{
    text-align: center;
}
table td{
    width: 24%;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> And when I put "width: 8%" it takes all the space of the page. Why?

That is a good question! I tried a few times, here is my observation:

Width of td is relative to it's parent, the tr. The tr is by default width:100% of the table.

Since you manipulate all the td tags, when you make them no longer fulfill the default 100% width of the table, the calculation of it's space may become buggy since this is not expected.

That would explain why, as soon as they're all < 25%, they begin to grow up.

The real question seems to be : **what do you want to do ?**

If you want the table to take larger or lesser space : manipulate it's width.

If you want some td to be larger than others : manipulate each of them while always making them all combined equal to the table width.

Comment: Thank you!! I just wanted to change the size of the table as a whole and keep the columns sizes equal (and not buggy when the window of the page is resized)...

Answer (score 2):

The total width should be 100%,

when you set width 20%, first cell width or other cell should be 40%.

---

please change style to:

```
table
{
    width: 100%;
    margin: 2.5%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    table-layout: fixed;
}

table td
{
    width: 20%;
}

table td:first-child
{
    width: 40%;
}
```

when you want to set style to first cell should be use below code

```
td:first-child
```

Comment: I didn't understand. I am setting just the first cell width?